# Realm. How to migrate with Date from outer class

Tags: java, realm

Now I have a schema like this:

```
class Entries {
 String name;
 Date date;
 RealmList<Entry> entries;
}

class Entry {
 int id;
 int hours;
 int minutes;
}
```

And now i need migrate to schema like this:

```
class Entry {
 int id;
 Date date;
}
```

So i need to take a date from Entries class, and set it to each Entry in list and set a hours and minutes from existing fields.

How I can do this via migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically you need to write following code (or something very similar):

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        // Migrate from version 0 to version 1
        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmObjectSchema entriesSchema = schema.get("Entries");
            RealmObjectSchema entrySchema = schema.get("Entry");

            entrySchema.addField("date", Date.class);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject> entriesList = realm.where("Entries").findAll();
            for (DynamicRealmObject entries : entriesList) {
                RealmList<DynamicRealmObject> entryList = entry.getList("entries");
                for (DynamicRealmObject entry : entryList) {
                    Date date = entries.getDate("date");
                    calendar.setTime(date);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, entry.getInt("hours"));
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTES, entry.getInt("minutes");
                    entry.setDate("date", calendar.getTime());
                }
            }
            entrySchema.removeField("hours");
            entrySchema.removeField("minutes");
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }

    // hashCode, equals
}
```

Comment: thanks. this is what I need. But now I dont understand, I need to leave Enrty class with unused fields like hours and minutes and I cant delete it?

Comment: The migration code I posted has `removeField("hours")` and `removeField("minutes")` at the end, so obviously not.

Comment: but it removes it from realm generated files, right?

Comment: I meant that you **can** delete the fields, but they'll be erased from the schema only when you also apply a migration that removes it from the schema. In fact, if you don't remove the fields in a migration, you'll get a `Field count expected to be 2 but was 4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DynamicRealm API just like the normal typed API to move the date. Something like:

```
RealmMigration migration = new RealmMigration() {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject> entries = realm.where("Entries").findAll();
        for (DynamicRealmObject entry : entries) {
            RealmList<DynamicRealmObject> entriesList = entry.getList("entries");
            for (DynamicRealmObject e : entriesList) {
                e.setDate("date", entry.getDate("date"));
            }
        }
    }
};
```